# Cant install Material UI to new react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

Im new to the dev world and I'm trying to start a new react app using material UI as the component library but I keep getting the following error:

[image: Error image]

And my files look like this:

[image: Folder screenshot]

Can anyone help in layman's terms?

TIA

Comment: try the newer version of material ui with react 18
```npm install @mui/material```

Comment: Still gave the same error.

Comment: `npm i mui/material emotion/react emotion/styled`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps @material-ui/core
```

this Material UI version does not support React v18 yet I suggest going for a lower version

Comment: Lower version of react?

Comment: yup you can still use it with command I posted but you might face bugs later on

Comment: What version of react would you recommend? and how do I pick a version? Sorry for noob questions

Comment: you can install the 16 since from the logs its supported npm install --save react@16.0.0 react-dom@16.0.0

Comment: Can I just insert into terminal in the current app or start fresh?

Comment: you can but some things might break because their version is for react 17 not 16 so take note of that also I just checked material ui should have a v5 released it supports react 17

Answer (score 0):

I just did this:

```
-> npx create-react-app travel-advisor (<- that's the name of my app)
-> npm install --save react@17.0.0 react-dom@17.0.0
```