# I'm getting errors that occurs when installing material-ui/core?

Tags: reactjs

Every time I tried I got this same issue:

```
Cannot install with both node versions out there. 

    npm i @material-ui/core

    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: dashboard-web-app@0.1.0
    npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
    npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
    npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! See C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-01T07_16_22_224Z-debug-0.log`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cant install Material UI to new react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672912/cant-install-material-ui-to-new-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the latest React version in your package.json already I suppose you want to use the latest material ui for react. Now you're trying to install the previous version of the library (4.12.4) which relies on react version being < 18. What you most likely need to do is install `@mui/material` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material. This one is the latest version of the library and works with the latest React.